# How to efficiently construct a dependency graph from a transitive pairwise relation?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, theory

The following algorithm is necessary in a code generation problem that I am tackling. My current algorithm is O(n^2) but I feel like there is a better way to do it.

Suppose I have a predicate function for computing whether x < y.

```
less?: (x:T, y:T) -> True|False
```

I know a-priori that this relation is transitive. Such that,

```
less?(a, b) and less?(b, c)
```

implies

```
less?(a, c)
```

I would like to compute the dependency graph for a set of objects (x1, ..., xn). It should look like:

```
x1 => (x2, x4, x5)
x2 => (x3)
x5 => (x7)
x10 => ()
etc...
```

where each node, xi, is associated with a list of xj such that less?(xj, xi) is true. The easiest way to compute this graph is to call less? on all possible pairs of (xi, xj). But the less? relation is expensive and I would like to minimize the calls to less?

Thanks for your help.

-Patrick

Comment: From algorithm complexity point of view, you can't do better than O(n^2): for a `less?` with a single `True` pair, you must look up every pair in the worst case before you discover it. Maybe more details about your relation can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the < relation is sufficiently expensive you might gain by maintaining a matrix in which to store the current state of knowledge about a vs b. We can have  a < b, !(a < b), or unknown. Then when you compute a comparison of a vs b, store that in the matrix and look for deductions about a vs c and b vs c for every possible c for which the result is as yet unknown. Do  you also have a < b => !(b < a)?

With e.g. a vs b and b vs c there are only a finite number of possibilities to check for compatibility and incompatibility to see where deductions are possible but clearly a < b and b < c => a < c. Because of this we also have a < b and !(a < c) => !(b < c). Perhaps if you write out all possibilities you can find more.

I would be inclined to slowly grow a square of known values, adding new variables one by one chosen in a random order, so at stage i you know the entire contents of the matrix for the first i randomly chosen variables. As you add each new variable I would compare it with the variables already worked on in a random order. You are making every deduction possible. If there is a very clever variable comparison order you might hope that with a random comparison order it will be close enough to the optimal order that you won't be much more inefficient than it.

I have my doubts about this in the worst case. If you never find a < b for any a, b, I think you have to check every possibility.